# Get property that does not exists on one type but exists on other

Tags: typescript

I have a React component that accept a parameter of two different types:

```
type PersonType = {
  name: string
  email: string 
  .... etc
}

type UserType = {
  uid: string
} & PersonType

....

function MyComponent(
  input: UserType | PersonType
) { ... }
```

I need to get `uid` from input. I'm trying to get it this way:

```
const uid = input.uid ?? undefined
```

But this way I'm getting the error: `Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'UserType | PersonType'` but the property exists on one type so it should give me `undefined` when it does not exists on other type.

How can I get the desired prop (even if it's `undefined`) from this input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply cast types:

```
const uid = ( input as any ).uid as PersonType[ 'uid' ] | undefined
```

First cast `input` as `any` so TS will not check if the property exists on the object then get desired prop and cast its value to type prop or `undefined` if it does’nt exist.

Answer (score 1):

probably the most correct way would be to check the fields on `input`, so something like

```
const isUser = (input:UnionType):input is UserType => 'uid' in input;

function MyComponent(input: UserType | PersonType) {
  if(isUser(input)){
    input.uid;
  }

}
```

assuming the type guard makes sense and whenever there is uid it is a `UserType`, or  you can just check the field directly in the code with `in`operator.

It's a pretty common issue, can check other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72466800/typescript-access-a-property-a-union-type-in-which-not-all-members-have-said-pro) and the links on that question for more details.

Comment: or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904032/how-to-get-optional-property-from-union is pretty well explained. It seems it would be simple but actually there's quite a lot to consider. But many times in practice it's not a huge deal and the general structure of your code can change to accommodate the type checking without having to do all of that.